# Sed and regex print only match

Tags: regex, sed

```
sed -er '.*(textsringhere.+?(?= ))(?:.*)((?>\d{4})-(?>\d{2})-(?>\d{2}) (?>\d{2}):(?>\d{2}):(?>\d{2})).* (ERROR.*)' errors.txt
```

Running the above command on my `errors.txt` file simply produces all the matching lines in that file.  I had assumed that adding `.*` to the beginning of my regex would have forced `sed` to replace the entire line with the matches?

**Sample**

Input:

```
Aug  2 16:36:37 App.Dev.thing1 839854b7-749-4f12-89e0-3ad002ab5ffe[[APP/PROC/WEB/0]] 2017-08-02 16:36:37 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
Aug  2 18:04:46 App.Dev.thing2 eaedf253-df57-4c12-ade6-ea73274dbbc4[[APP/PROC/WEB/0]] 2017-08-02 18:04:46 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
Aug  3 01:45:55 App.Dev.thing2 eaedf253-df57-4c12-ade6-ea73274dbbc4[[APP/PROC/WEB/0]] 2017-08-03 01:45:55 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.c.v.b.m.c.i.thing2 - Error Processing Batch, this batch will be consumed individually`
```

Expected output:

```
App.Dev.thing1 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
App.Dev.thing2 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
App.Dev.thing2 ERROR c.c.v.b.m.c.i.thing2 - Error Processing Batch, this batch will be consumed individually`
```

Comment: FWIW I also couldn't get `grep -o` to work

Comment: also tried adding the substitution param `'s.*....../)`

Comment: tried `sed -er 's/(textsringhere.+?(?= ))(?:.*)((?>\d{4})-(?>\d{2})-(?>\d{2}) (?>\d{2}):(?>\d{2}):(?>\d{2})).* (ERROR.*).*/\1/' errors.txt`

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: sed doesn't support the pcre like regex you are using... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -E 's/.*(App\.\S+).+(ERROR .*)$/\1 \2/' errors.txt
```

The output:

```
App.Dev.thing1 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
App.Dev.thing2 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
App.Dev.thing2 ERROR c.c.v.b.m.c.i.thing2 - Error Processing Batch, this batch will be consumed individually
```